# Upgrading from PhoneGap to Native

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, local-storage

I have a PhoneGap application and i use HTML5 LocalStorage so save user data (like user token, username, etc.).

The thing is, that recently we decided to move from PhoneGap to Native Android application. But there is one thing i need to solve:

Is it possible to fetch the data from HTML5 LocalStorage using java code? We don't want users to be logged out after the update, so i need a way to fetch the user token from that LocalStorage and save it in the SharedPreferences.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prakash pointed me to right direction, but there are a few things missing:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface { //the class and the callbacks must be public
    @JavascriptInterface //this is needed for android 4.2 and above
    public void someCallback(String jsResult) {
        // this will be passed the local storage name variable
    }
}
```

There are a few settings to configure for the webView:

```
public void importPhoneGapUser() {
    String databasePath = getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    String pathToCache = getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();

    WebView mAuthWebView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = mAuthWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(pathToCache);
    webSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(databasePath);

    webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1048576);

    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mAuthWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface (), "JsInterface");

    //i wasn't able to run JS through 'javascript:' protocol, so i had to use a HTML file
    mAuthWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/import_auth.html");
}
```

Hope this will help someone someday

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. To execute JavaScript and get response you can do as follows:

Define JavaScript callback interface in your code:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
public void someCallback(String jsResult) {
     // this will be passed the local storage name variable
 }
 }
```

Attach this callback to your WebView:

```
MyJavaScriptInterface javaInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
webView.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "HTMLOUT");

 Run your JavaScript calling window.HTMLOUT.someCallback from the script:

 webView.loadUrl("javascript:( function () { var name = window.localStorage['name'];  
 window.HTMLOUT.someCallback(name); } ) ()");
```

Note - window.localStorage['name'] is the same as window.localStorage.getItem('name')

This post here on stackoverflow helped me

You might need to use super.webView.addJavascriptInterface or super.addJavascriptInterface to add the interface. You might need to use super.webView.loadUrl or super.loadUrl to invoke this. It all depends on where you are going to be calling these from.